# Yui Compressor Files Not Flushed Before Jar Packaging

Tags: java, css, maven, jar, yui-compressor

I am using the Maven yui compressor plugin, and the Maven one jar plugin to create a jar file that containers js and css resources.  It seems, though, that my compressed css files are always "one compile behind", meaning I have to compile the app twice to pick up a css change.  Here is the pom section for my build plugins

```
        <!-- Coffee -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.iron9light</groupId>
            <artifactId>coffeescript-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <srcDir>src/main/resources</srcDir>
                <outputDir>src/main/resources</outputDir>
                <bare>false</bare>
                <modifiedOnly>false</modifiedOnly>
                <allowedDelete>true</allowedDelete>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>coffeescript</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Sass -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jasig.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sassSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</sassSourceDirectory>
                <destination>src/main/resources</destination>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- YUI Compressor -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <suffix>.min</suffix>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Compiler -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.example.application.web.JettyStarter</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- One Jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <onejarVersion>0.97</onejarVersion>
                        <classifier>onejar</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I check my source tree, I see that the minified css is there, but its not in the jar.  I want to compare this to "flushing" the file out prior to one-jar packaging.  Has anyone seen this before?

Example:  I added this to style.css

```
.clear-both {
    clear: both;
}
```

And in style.min.css in the source tree

```
.clear-both{clear:both;}
```

But when I request this file over the server:

```
GET css/style.min.css
```

that line is not there.

Could this be related to the order of plugin execution with the resources plugin:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MyApp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 661 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.1:compress (default) @ MyApp ---
...
```

Comment: I have updated the answer but it can be improved. What all are present in your src/main/resources directory? Does it only have .coffee scripts and saas source files?

Comment: Good questions, yes, the key was to put them in the process-sources phase.  I'll have a look at the project.build.directory too, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's due to the fact that the `maven-resources-plugin` was executed prior to the `yuicompressor-maven-plugin` and hence your minified files weren't copied over to the final jar.

Rearranging the phases, will help you resolve this,but the best way to tackle this is to avoid  generating minified/compressed/compiled files within the source tree. These files shouldn't be part of your source tree, but should be generated into your build's output directory. Use Maven's `${project.build.directory}` (the target directory) for all kinds of manipulations and processing. This will also make sure that all generated files are always cleaned up during a maven build(mvn clean install)

Have a look at the below build snippet. I have included comments where necessary. The snippet was made under the assumption that all your coffee scripts(.coffee files), saas templates(.scss files), other css(uncompressed .css files) , js(uncompressed .js files) and other files(say images etc) are all present in src/main/resources. The snippet will only package minified js and css and uncompressed js/css won't be packaged into the jar.

If you want to test this, remove all the generated css files, js files and minified files from src\main\resources before you execute any maven builds with this snippet.

```
<build>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <!-- removing coffee scripts, saas templates, js and css from the final 
            output,we will only allow compressed files to go into the final jar
            maven-resources-plugin:resources will respect these exclusions -->
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/**.coffee</exclude>
            <exclude>**/**.scss</exclude>
            <exclude>**/**.css</exclude>
            <exclude>**/**.js</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <!-- copy uncompressed css and js to a staging directory for compressing -->
            <execution>
                <id>copy-uncompressed-css-and-js</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.js</include>
                                <include>**/*.css</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/uncompressed-css-and-js</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <!-- Coffee -->
    <!-- compiling coffee scripts and generating the uncompressed js files 
        into a staging directory for compressing -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.iron9light</groupId>
        <artifactId>coffeescript-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <srcDir>src/main/resources/coffee</srcDir>
            <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/uncompressed-css-and-js</outputDir>
            <bare>false</bare>
            <modifiedOnly>false</modifiedOnly>
            <allowedDelete>true</allowedDelete>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>coffeescript</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <!-- Sass -->
    <!-- compiling saas scripts and generating the uncompressed css files 
        into a staging directory for compressing -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jasig.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>saas</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <sassSourceDirectory>src/main/resources/saas</sassSourceDirectory>
            <destination>${project.build.directory}/uncompressed-css-and-js</destination>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <!-- YUI Compressor -->
    <!-- compressing all css/jss files in the staging directory and generating 
        the output in the target/classes folder(which will end up in the final jar -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>compress</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compress</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <suffix>.min</suffix>
            <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/uncompressed-css-and-js</sourceDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Reference : Have a look at the ordering of phases in the [Maven default lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put the CoffeeScript, Sass, and YUI compression in the process sources phase

```
<phase>process-sources</phase>
```